# Сохранение информации при переходе между страницами проекта ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Столкнулся с проблемой сохранения информации при открытии новых страниц в проекте ASP.NET.

Я заполняю xml-файл данными которые пользователь забивает в текстбоксы. А потом они уже из xml-ки пишутся в таблицу но суть не в этом. Первые 3 поля я беру из 3 других таблиц. То есть захожу с помощью кнопки на новую страницу. Кликаю в таблице нужную мне строку и читаю айдишник строки. Но при этом каждый раз когда я иду на новую страницу потом этот айдишник сотрётся.

И нечего бы страшного если бы таких поля было бы 2. Я бы направил просто считанный айдишник редиректом на новую страницу. Способ муторный но я бы сохранил данные. Но проблема в том что поля 3 и я теряю 1 из айдишников по любому.

Есть какой то способ попроще как сохранить данные на странице не зависимо от моих переходов пока я читаю остальные айдишники? Спасибо за ответ заранее. Если что то не понятно объяснил, спрашивайте. Приложу весь необходимый код.

Comment: @Mike если можете помогите пожалуйста в этом вопросе.

Comment: Тема закрыта. Нашёл вариант. Просто создал класс в который складываю нужные айдишники и там они нормально хранятся.

Comment: Это неправильно, тема не закрыта. "Класс" этот у Вас - статический, то есть разные пользователи, будут писать туда данные одновременно.

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему нельзя отказаться от XML-файла, если уже есть таблица в базе - значит есть база. Была бы классическая вебформа: показали форму, записали из формы в базу. Но нет, обязательно нужно лететь из Москвы в Питер через Владивосток, создавать себе самому проблемы на ровном месте, бороться, побеждать и думать, какой я молодец.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 2):

Для сохранения данных при переходе между страницами можно использовать объект Session. Также можно использовать объект Cache. И есть еще вариант с TempData. Вариант с сессией в вашем случае будет предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 1):

Три варианта передачи данных между страницами:

1. Запрос - `QueryString` или данные формы;
2. Сессия.
3. Постоянное хранилище, например, база данных.

Для Вас, я думаю, больше всего подходит сессия - свойство `Session` существует как в контроллере (MVC), так и в странице (WebForms).